# Trouble looping and remove createjs "on" eventListener with "off"

Tags: easeljs

Im trying to loop and remove eventlistener in createjs:

```
    Actor = function() {

    this.update = true;
    this.offset;
    this.instance;


    this.member = function(a_obj) {
count++;

        this._container = a_obj.container;
        this._images = a_obj.images;
        this._name = a_obj.name;
        this._top = a_obj.top;
        this._left = a_obj.left;

        getCirTest = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult(this._images));
        getCirTest.name = this._name;
        getCirTest.y = this._top + 10;
        getCirTest.x = this._left + 10;
        getCirTest.scaleX = 0.8;
        getCirTest.scaleY = 0.8;
        getCirTest.cursor = "pointer";
        this._container.addChild(getCirTest);

         holdsAllObj[count]=getCirTest;

       console.log(holdsAllObj);


      md = getCirTest.on("mousedown", activate);

       function activate(evt) {

            myCurrentTarget = evt.currentTarget;
            xyCor.push(evt.currentTarget.x, evt.currentTarget.y);

            this.parent.addChild(this);
            this.offset = {
                x: this.x - evt.stageX,
                y: this.y - evt.stageY
            };
        }

 pm = getCirTest.on("pressmove", move);

     function move(evt) {

            myintersect(evt.currentTarget, getCenterBitmap);

            this.x = evt.stageX + this.offset.x;
            this.y = evt.stageY + this.offset.y;
            update = true;
        }


 cc = getCirTest.on("click", release);


        function release (evt) {
            countClicks++;


          holdsAllObj[1].off("mousedown",md);
          holdsAllObj[1].off("pressmove",pm);

            console.log();

            if (soundPlay == true && countClicks == 1) {


                console.log("im true");
                mySoundInstance = createjs.Sound.play(evt.currentTarget.name);
                mySoundInstance.addEventListener("complete", createjs.proxy(handleSoundComplete, mySoundInstance));


            } else {
                createjs.Sound.stop(evt.currentTarget.name);
                countClicks = 0;
            }

            console.log(countClicks);

            update = true;
        }




    } //**** END: members ****

}
```

Its my getCirTest, whichs have an event:

```
 md = getCirTest.on("mousedown", activate);
```

It´s create 10 instance of a bitmap object like this:

```
 for (var circles = 0; circles < 10; circles++) {

          var x = Math.round(container.width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - 150 / 2);
          var y = Math.round(container.width / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - 150 / 2);



          var MP = new Actor();

          MP.member({
              container: container,
              images: myFTMImages[circles],
              name: myFTMNames[circles],
              top: y,
              left: x
          });

          angle += step;



      }
```

My problem is that i would like to remove the eventListeners in a event:

```
cc = getCirTest.on("click", release);


        function release (evt) {

}
```

Thats why i have put the bitmaps in a array:

```
holdsAllObj[count]=getCirTest;
```

And then tried the following:

```
cc = getCirTest.on("click", release);


                function release (evt) {

    for(var ijk=0;ijk<holdsAllObj.length;ijk++){
          holdsAllObj[ijk].off("mousedown",md);
              holdsAllObj[ijk].off("pressmove",pm);
    }


    }
```

unfortunately .. it´does not work for me ...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with js scope.  JS methods are called in the window context rather than the context they are created.  You can use the createjs.proxy method to apply a scope to a method call, like this:

`cc = getCirTest.on("click", release, this);`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I fixed the code snippet. The `on()` method has a scope parameter, which is recommended over a proxy/bind call. Note that to remove the listener, you need to store the result of the `on()` call, and use that instead of the callback function.

Comment: Not sure if I can follow you :-)

Comment: You said: "you need to store the result of the on() call, and use that instead of the callback function". Can you give an example ... Lanny.

Comment: on and addEventListener return a function reference, which you need in order to remove it.  check out the documentation for [removeEventListener](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_removeEventListener)

Comment: Hi, I want to remove a listener (the only) to "tick" of the Ticker class in createjs. However none of the approaches work. When I hand in the reference created by addEventListener the Tick won't stop. Using on/off didn't help either. Any ideas?

Comment: This is my code: window.myTest = createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', this.handleTick.bind(this)); Then later: createjs.Ticker.removeEventListener('tick', window.myTest);